# BigTable with C# Library

Tags: c#, linq, google-app-engine, bigtable

Is there any sort of LinqToBigTable library out there or anything that makes it link up with C#? I am looking to integrate with App Engine BigTable.

Comment: AppEngine have Datastore which runs on BigTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to interact with the AppEngine datastore from outside of an AppEngine application. Can't be done.

Your best bet for making something like this work is to expose your AppEngine datastore through a RESTful interface that talks JSON. Then, you can use [Linq-to-JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) to work with the data in the fashion you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported languages for the Google App Engine are Python and Java (plus Go, experimentally). See [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#language). As neither is a .net language you can't use Linq with the Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [C# client library for Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp), but there is not one for App Engine.